# Number to words in left to right direction

Tags: java, interview-questions, converting, numbers-to-words

I have faced this question in an interview:

> If we enter a number it will convert into individual strings and display in same order.
>
> **Ex:** If I enter `564` then the output should be `FIVE SIX FOUR`.

I have written the following working code (of course it has some limitations).  Suggest any possible ways of optimizing this code.

```
public class NoToWord {

    public static void main(String[] a)
    {
        int no = 0;
        String[] words= new String[]{"ZERO","ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE"};
        String[] word=new String[10];

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            no = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int i,j;
        j=0;
        while(no>0){
            i = no%10;
            no /= 10;
            word[j] = words[i];
            j++;
        }
        for(int k= word.length;k>0;k--)
        {
            System.out.println(word[k-1]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about -1? how would you handle it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code:

```
int i,j;
j=0;
while(no>0){
    i = no%10;
    no /= 10;
    word[j] = words[i];
    j++;
}
for(int k= word.length;k>0;k--)
{
    System.out.println(word[k-1]+" ");
}
```

can be drastically simplified to:

```
String numbers = String.valueOf(no);
for(int i = 0 ;i<numbers.length(); i++){
    System.out.print(words[Character.getNumericValue(numbers.charAt(i))]+" ");
}
```

---

Or you may save save the user input as `String` (but make sure it **only** contains digits). You will have something like this:

```
 String numbers = br.readLine();
 for(int i = 0 ;i<numbers.length(); i++){
    System.out.print(words[Character.getNumericValue(numbers.charAt(i))]+" ");
}
```

Comment: this code is perfect and working fine(I tried). But is there any common code(not in java like algorithm) for all languages?

Comment: You mean if there's a way that doesn't rely/heavily rely on Java methods... (not algos)?

Answer (score 4):

Besides the points mentioned by @DnR, I'm not sure why you choose to create a 10-element resultant `String` array. You can just use `System.out.print()` in your `while` loop to print the word out, remembering to use `StringBuilder` to `reverse()` the input `String` first.

Also, if you want to stay away from `Character.getNumericValue()` you can try these:

```
int zero = '0' - 48; // will be 0
int one = '1' - '0'; // similar
```

A character value minus the character '0' or the number 48 gives you the number to pass to your String array (because `'0'` has an integer value of 48 in ASCII).

I'll also advocate `number` over `no` at the very least... it's easier to read.

Comment: You should actually just subtract '0' out. :) Like: `int val = myString[i] - '0';`

Comment: @fluffy that's a good point. :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, this should be much more eficient, by only using one loop:

```
public class NoToWord {

    public static void main(String[] a){
        int no = 0;
        String[] words= new String[]{"ZERO","ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE"};
        String[] word=new String[10];

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            no = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String numbers = String.valueOf(no);

        for(int i = 0 ;i<numbers.length(); i++){
            System.out.print(words[Character.getNumericValue(numbers.charAt(i))]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code is perfect and working fine(I tried). But is there any common code(not in java like algorithm) for all languages?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is good to validate your input. You do it by parsing it to an `Integer`. You could also make a method that uses `Character.isDigit()` for all characters in your `String`. That way you can act on arbitraty length input.

If the input is valid, you can simply loop over the characters in the input and convert them. While you can use the 'trick' from h.j.k.'s answer, I prefer using explicit methods to convert digits to `int`.

You can even combine these methods

```
for (char c : input.toCharArray())
{
   if (!Character.isDigit(c))
   {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("'input' contains invalid characters");
   }
   int index = Character.digit(c, 10);
   ...
}
```