# SHOUTY_SNAKE_CASED NUMBERS

Tags: java, rags-to-riches, numbers-to-words

WE_ALL_LOVE_[SHOUTY_SNAKE_CASE](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25733259#25733259)_SO_I_WROTE_A_PROGRAM_FOR_IT!!1!

Alright, enough of this. This is a [rags-to-riches](/questions/tagged/rags-to-riches) from [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51475/number-to-words-in-left-to-right-direction). The pattern is pretty simple, it takes a `String` input, verifies if it is numerical, and if so, converts it to SHOUTY_SNAKE_CASE.

> Example : "1231" -> "ONE_TWO_THREE_ONE"

It is fairly simple but it is also the first time I used the Java 8's streams, so I wanted an opinion on my (simple) use of it.

```
private static final String[] words = 
        new String[]{"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};

public static String convertNumbersToWords(final String input) {

    if(input == null || !input.matches("^\\d*$")){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input cannot be null or non-numerical.");
    }

    return input.chars()
             .mapToObj(c -> getWordFromCharCode(c).toUpperCase())
             .collect(Collectors.joining("_"));
}

private static String getWordFromCharCode(int code){
    return words[code - 48];
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly few SHOUTY_SNAKE_CASE variables and text in this code?!

Comment: I came here expecting this to be PCG, not CR. Disappointed.

Comment: @fluffy It's simple now. You see a logo that means "not fully graduated", you're on PCG :p

Comment: @holroy It's Java, not LOLCODE.

Comment: ArnoldC is definitely made for shouty stuff

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you need an *enum*erated set of `LOUD_WORDS` that aligns with numbers, preferably as some form of numeric indices... an `enum` instead of `String[]` seems to be the perfect fit:

```
enum Word {
    ZERO, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE;
}
```

(I think you can figure out the derivation.)

**edit:** Just one note about using `Word.values()` as pointed out in [@Simon](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112044/shouty-snake-cased-numbers/112066?noredirect=1#comment206907_112066)'s comments: it creates a new array each time and this may not be desirable, performance-wise.

Since you're also experimenting with some of the Java 8 features, you may want to consider using an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) too, to eliminate the `if`-validation:

```
private static final String NUMBERS_ONLY = "^\\d+$";

// Usage
Optional.ofNullable(input)
        .filter(v -> v != null && v.matches(NUMBERS_ONLY))
        .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new)
        .chars()
        // ...
```

If you prefer to throw `NullPointerException` for `null` values, you can stick with `Optional.of(T)`.

Comment: How would you recommend to map from the digit to the String? Do a `Word.values()[digit]` for each call?

Comment: @SimonForsberg yeah, `.map(i -> Character.getNumericValue(i)).mapToObj(i -> Word.values()[i].toString())`...

Comment: @h.j.k. `Word.values()` creates a new array each and every time it is called. Storing all the values in one array once sounds better to me, and it's not like you'll create a `Word w = Word.THREE;` or anything. Sounds like a `String[]` is better to me.

Comment: I'd be a bit wary of using an enum to represent actual output values. For example, this could cause problems should you ever wish to support other languages with non-Latin characters. Using a `String[]` (or even `Map<Integer, String>`) also feels more semantically correct to me, though that's arguable.

Answer (score 36):

Why are you storing them as lowercase words only to call `toUpperCase` on them? Store them in the form you intend to use them and save yourself a function call on each word. It's also more understandable to have the strings stored the same way 
they'll be printed.

Answer (score 21):

I would propose replacing the kinda low-level `code - 48` with `Character.getNumericValue`.

Another consideration might be to use guava's `CharMatcher.DIGIT.matchesAllOf` instead of the regex for validating the input string, though I realize that using libraries is often besides the point for CR.stackexchange.
Note that this approach would pass you digits with numeric values bigger than 9 as well (i.e. roman numeral 50) and you'd have to think of a way to support them. (Split to single digits?)

Comment: Proposing libraries is a good idea! :) It's just that you need to be cautious not to center the whole review over the use of an external library. But your answer is good, thanks! :)

Comment: Can `code - 48` be replaced with `code - '0'`? (which is still not perfect, but better IMO)

Comment: @oliverpool: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/303553/is-it-better-to-check-c-0-or-c-48 :)

Comment: Filter with Character.isDigit, convert with Character.getNumericValue, then filter again to restrict to the range 0 - 9.

Answer (score 12):

#### Naming and method decomposition

Let's take a look at this method signature:

> ```
> public static String convertNumbersToWords(final String input) {
> ```

The method name suggests converting *numbers*... And it works with inputs like "1234". It's a bit unnatural that the input is a string, as opposed to a numeric type, and "1234" is one number, not plural numbers.

In addition, the method does two things:

- validate the input consists of digits only
- convert the digits to `SHOUT_CASE`

It would be better to decompose this to two methods, for example:

```
private static String convertValidatedDigitsToWords(final String digits) {
    return digits.chars()
            .mapToObj(ShoutySnake::getWordFromCharCode)
            .collect(Collectors.joining("_"));
}

public static String convertDigitsToWords(final String input) {
    if (input == null || !input.matches("\\d*")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input cannot be null or non-numerical.");
    }
    return convertValidatedDigitsToWords(input);
}
```

... and perhaps add an overloading for numeric input:

```
public static String convertDigitsToWords(final int number) {
    if (number < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input must be non-negative");
    }
    return convertValidatedDigitsToWords(Integer.toString(number));
}
```

A small related tip: `String.matches` implies `^` and `$`, no need to include that in the pattern.

#### Optimizing for repeated calls

If you expect the method to be called repeatedly,
then it would be good to compile the regular expression.

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d*");

public static String convertDigitsToWords(final String input) {
    if (!pattern.matcher(input).matches()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input must be non-null and non-negative.");
    }
    return convertValidatedDigitsToWords(input);
}
```

#### Magic number 48

In this code, 48 is a magic number:

> ```
> private static String getWordFromCharCode(int code){
>     return words[code - 48];
> }
> ```

You can easily make it less magic by referring to `'0'` instead:

```
private static String getWordFromCharCode(int code) {
    return words[code - '0'];
}
```

Comment: Awesome, combine this with @benjaminssp's advice to replace `code - 48` with `Character.getNumericValue` and I think you've got your answer :)

Comment: Thanks @user1477388, your comment inspired me to add another section ;-) (*Magic number 48*)

Answer (score 10):

The name `convertNumbersToWords()` does not clearly reflect what the method is doing. You can either do this using the java convention like `convertNumbersToShoutySnakeCaseWords()` or in a way it matches the purpose of the application like `CONVERT_NUMBERS_TO_SHOUTY_SNAKE_CASE_WORDS()`

Comment: `snakeShouts()` could also be an option if you value humor above professionalism

Comment: Just because the code is about shouty and snake case things, doesn't mean that the code itself should be shouty and snakey.

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest to change three thinks which haven't been mentioned yet.

1. Your regex works but is not what I call "easy on the eyes". What about the following:

   ```
   ^[0-9]*$
   ```

   When I read something like this I immediately think: "Some regex with number filters."
2. Also same topic. Do you actually want to allow empty inputs? I would suggest not. Replace `*` with `+`:

   ```
   ^[0-9]+$
   ^\\d+$
   ```
3. I like static imports. It is not everyone's favourite, but in my opinion, it makes the code more readable. That is why this would be my final solution:

   ```
   import java.util.Optional;
   import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

   public class ShoutySnake {

       private enum WORDS{ZERO,ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX,SEVEN,EIGHT,NINE}

       private static final String NUMBERS_ONLY = "^[0-9]+$";

       private static String getNumericalCharAsSnakeShoutCaseWord(final int codePoint){
           return WORDS.values()[Character.getNumericValue(codePoint)].name();
       }

       public static String convertNumbersToShoutySnakeCaseWords(final String input) {
           return Optional.ofNullable(input)
               .filter(s -> s.matches(NUMBERS_ONLY))
               .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("input cannot be null, empty or non-numerical."))
               .chars()
               .mapToObj(ShoutySnake::getNumericalCharAsSnakeShoutCaseWord)
               .collect(joining("_"));
       }
   }
   ```